# Why isn't ConcurrentHashMap working here?

Tags: java, concurrenthashmap, thread-local

This is the constructor:

```
    public LoaderImpl ()
    {
        fileName2ModifiedMap_ = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, Boolean>();
        fileName2NameMap_ = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, String>();
        rule2FileNameMap_ = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, String>();
        rule2RuleFileMap_ = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, RuleFile>();
        ruleName2RunnerMap_ = new ThreadLocal<Map<String, Runner>>();
    }
```

I am reading this piece of code and wondering why is a ThreadLocal used for protecting the map? Why can't a ConcurrentHashMap work as well, as the first 4 maps? Or it's just the author's preferences in choosing one of the two.

Comment: ThreadLocal isolates map objects so each thread accesses its own copy. ConcurrentHashMap provides concurrent access from multiple threads to the same copy.

Comment: *"used for protecting the map"* It's not *protecting* the map, it is creating a *holder* that will then be used to store a *different* map for each thread using the `LoaderImpl` class. Note that those maps aren't created here. The `ThreadLocal` holder is empty (for now). The first 4 maps will be *shared* across thread. The 5th is for *unshared*, aka thread-local, maps. --- Kind of like how `static` fields are shared across object instances, and a non-static field is instance-local.

Comment: @AlexanderPavlov, my real question is why are these two different methods are used? My understanding is that both ConcurrentHashMap and ThreadLoca here are to ensure data in the maps won't be corrupted by multiple threads.  Can I replace the last ThreadLocal object with a ConcurrentHashMap object?

Comment: @Andreas, why does the author choose to let  one map shared while the other isn't shared but both are thread safe?

Comment: @ling Who says the maps that will be put into the thread-local holder are thread-safe? They very likely are not, because the entire purpose of using a thread-local holder is that each thread will have their own object, which will not be shared with any other thread, so it doesn't need to be thread-safe. --- As for why the code *needs* (not really a choice, but a requirement) a separate map for each thread is impossible for us to answer, since we don't know what this code is all about.

Comment: @Andreas at the end of the day, the ThreadLocal serves the same purpose of producing thread safety code, i.e. each thread gets its own copy of the instance. I am learning to know when I should choose to use ConcurrentHashMap or a ThreadLocal map?

Comment: @ling Absolutely not. *Thread safety* code is code that allow ***shared access*** to a single object by multiple threads. *Thread-local* is used when the code want objects where threads ***don't share access***, by giving each thread a *separate* object. It is certainly not "same purpose".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203146/discussion-between-ling-and-andreas).